# Prevent Kendo UI tooltip from displaying when loading ajax content

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui, tooltip

I'm using kendo tooltips configured to retrieve data via an ajax call. I'd like to prevent the tooltip from displaying if the ajax call yields no data. I've tried the code below, but this causes the tooltip to flash open before hiding - because `destroy()` calls all the bound events. Any ideas?

```
$('input[data-isreadonly="True"]').kendoTooltip({
        content: { url: options.GetCalculatedDependenciesUrl },
        position: 'right',
        width: 400,
        requestStart: function (e) {
            e.options.url = e.options.url.replace('-1', e.target.data('varid')).replace('-2', e.target.data('surveyyear'));
        },
        contentLoad: function () {
            if (this.content[0].innerHTML.length === 0) {
                // this.popup.destroy();  // no additional affect
                this.destroy();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?